# powershell - only use argument by name

Tags: function, powershell, arguments

I have a function that looks somthing like this:

```
function plk(){
    $cmd = $args -join ' '
    plink user@myserver -i key.ppk $cmd
}
```

This function works great, however I wish to add a new argument that will enable me to change the server (but keep `myserver` as default if I don't name my server). so I changed my code to this:

```
function plk($server = 'myserver'){
    $cmd = $args -join ' '
    plink user@$server -i key.ppk $cmd
}
```

However, PowerShell seems to think that my first argument is my `$server` variable.

Meaning if I use my function like: `plk ls /folder`, PowerShell would think that `ls` is `$server`.

I want to fix this that only if I do: `plk -server 'server' ls /folder`, PowerShell would switch the server, and using `plk ls /folder` would use my default.

Answer (score 1):

I would define the parameters within a `Param` block, add one parameter for `$Server` and one for the remaining `$Arguments`.

Then you could use the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` property:

> The ValueFromRemainingArguments argument indicates that the parameter
>           accepts all of the parameters values in the command that are not
>           assigned to other parameters of the function.

Source: [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx)

**Script:**

```
function plk
{
    Param
    (
       [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
       [string[]]$Arguments,

       [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
       [string]$Server = 'myServer'
    )

    $cmd = $Arguments -join ' '
    plink user@$Server -i key.ppk $cmd
}
```

Comment: yes, didn't work. it kept thinking my first argument was the server.

Comment: you are right, I changed my script. Please try again.

Comment: it works only if I enter -server flag, otherwise it still detect the first argument to be $server

Comment: You could instead specify the `-Argument` parameter explicit and comma seperate the values: `plk -Arguments ls, /folder`